# 2d array average and total c++

Tags: c++, for-loop, multidimensional-array, 2d

it has to appear like this:
[image: it has to appear like this]

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{


    float allsales[3] [2] = {{1200.33, 2350.75}, {3677.80, 2456.05}, {750.67, 1345.99}};
    float totalsales = 0, ave = 0, sum = 0;



       for (int row = 0; row < 3; row++)
       {
           cout << "Ave sale for store "<< row + 1 << ": ";

        for (int col=0; col < 2; col++)
        {


           totalsales += allsales [row] [col];
           sum = 0; // I cant figure out how to code the formula for the sum
           ave = sum / 2;
           cout << ave <<endl;


        }

        

    }

    cout << "Total sales : $" << totalsales << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Also, Im a first year prog student so I cant use some advanced codes/commands etc.,. I can only stick on nested for loops, if else, while

Comment: Imho `std::vector` and standard algorithms are not advanced. c arrays and hand written algorithms are advanced. Writing code by restricting yourself to only for loops, if-else and while, is more difficult than using the right tools

Comment: I am not sure you want to calculate the average each iteration of the inner loop. sum probably should be a local variable in the outer loop initialized to 0 each iteration of the outer loop. The formula for sum would be the same as totalsales

Comment: you have to be more specific what you are trying to achieve. what should `sum` be the sum of? of the two entries for one row?

Comment: check how often you output an "average" - an average per value isn't an average, it's the value itself... you might want to move it to an outer loop...

Comment: I cant use the same formula of totalsales for the sum otherwise, what I can't figure out is the way to get the sum separately umm.. somewhat like this [0][0] and [0][1] so on and so forth

Comment: The issue is that your `float` array conveys no information as to what the first and second items mean.  If you had used a `struct` with two member variables, and those member variables were named appropriately, and had an array of those, then others would understand immediately what those two columns represent (note, you've spent time trying to explain in words what those columns mean, and that wouldn't have been the case otherwise).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How would you do it by hand?

*I* would start `sum` with an initial value of zero for each row, add to it each element in that row, and then compute the average at the end of the row.

(Don't forget that you can declare variables in other places than first thing in a function.)

And I would also probably first sum the row, and then add the "row sum" to the total.

Like this:

```
for (int row = 0; row < 3; row++)
{
    float sum = 0;
    for (int col = 0; col < 2; col++)
    {
        sum += allsales[row][col];
    }
    cout << "Ave sale for store "<< row + 1 << ": " << sum / 2 << endl;
    totalsales += sum;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
float allsales[3] [2] = {{1200.33, 2350.75}, {3677.80, 2456.05}, {750.67, 1345.99}};
float totalsales = 0, ave = 0, sum = 0;

   for (int row = 0; row < 3; row++)
   {
       cout << "Ave sale for store "<< row + 1 << ": ";
       sum = 0;
       for (int col=0; col < 2; col++)
       {
            totalsales += allsales[row][col];
            sum += allsales[row][col];
       }
        ave = sum / 2;
        cout << ave <<endl;
    }

cout << "Total sales : $" << totalsales << endl;
return 0;
```

the only difference between sum and totalsales, is that sum is only for one row at a time, so it needs to be initialized to zero before the start of the second loop. also average needs to be calculated after the inner loop, once calculation of one row of sum is complete.

try dry running the code to understand for loops better